# How do I send an attachment with an email in Racket?

Tags: email, smtp, lisp, scheme, racket

I looked at the [net/smtp](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/smtp.html) module which provides several functions for sending emails. However, it does not say anything about including attachments. I also used the search feature on the Racket documentation website to look for the word "attach" and nothing relevant was returned.

I have searched and searched, but to no avail. So, how do I attach files to emails in Racket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email attachments use MIME.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a built-in module that will do MIME encoding. (There is one, `net/mime`, for doing MIME decoding.)

I've searched PLaneT too, and there, the closest library for that is `bzlib/mime`, but there's no documentation for it, so I can't tell you if it will do the job or not.

Answer (score 4):

Sirmail does that, I believe:  https://github.com/mflatt/sirmail

Comment: It probably just does MIME encoding manually, which as Chris pointed out is how it must be done if there is no module.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exclusively-racket solution, but the [Racket API for mutt](https://docs.racket-lang.org/mutt/index.html) might help you achieve what you're ultimately looking to accomplish.